# "javaw" is an unrecognized command

Tags: windows-7, java

I'm using some Open University software, SB-BASE, that as far as I understand has been written in Java, but the batch file will not run and returns an error stating the "javaw" command is not recognise.

Can anyone suggest why this isn't working? The software installs without any problems and I'm using a Windows 7 machine with admin rights.

Comment: Check your java folder if there is inside of the bin folder a javaw file. If yes maybe you have to set java_home, that the batch script will find the javaw file see here: http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/2.0/docs/setting-java-home.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the right place for this kind of questions, as we just deal with programming things, but you should check your system path to see if it includes java's dirs.

Take a look here:

http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

http://bharatsoft.blogspot.it/2010/08/setting-path-and-classpath-in-javahow.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help folks, I appreciate this is for programming problems, but I was advised to try the site by a colleague.

It turned out the installation process was a bit clunky and didn't like being installed on the D drive with the OS and Java on the C drive, so the shortcut didn't work.

Again, thanks for taking the time to respond.

Best wishes,
Andrew

Comment: Once the two day limit has passed please do not forget to mark your own answer as "accepted" otherwise every few months this question will float back up to the front page as a "question without a accepted answer"